# Ruby method with undetermined number of arguments

Tags: ruby

I am working through App Academy's free ruby curriculum and am having trouble with methods that take in multiple arguments.

The method:

```
  should accept any number of arrays of the same length as arguments
  should return a 2D array where each subarray contains the elements at the same index from each argument
```

Breaking this down, I tried using the Array#zip method but I'm not sure how to write it when there are an unspecified number of arguments.

```
def zip(array, *arrays)
    array.zip(arrays)
end
```

The above method works when I enter just two arguments, but when you add more than that, it's producing an unintended output.

Should produce:

```
describe "zip" do
    let(:array_1) { ['a', 'b', 'c'] }
    let(:array_2) { [1, 2, 3] }
    let(:array_3) { ['w', 'x', 'y'] }

    it "should accept any number of arrays of the same length as arguments" do
        expect { zip(array_1) }.to_not raise_error
        expect { zip(array_1, array_2) }.to_not raise_error
        expect { zip(array_1, array_2, array_3) }.to_not raise_error
    end

    it "should return a 2D array where each subarray contains the elements at the same index from each argument" do
        expect(zip(array_1, array_2)).to eq([
            ["a", 1],
            ["b", 2],
            ["c", 3]
        ])

        expect(zip(array_2, array_1)).to eq([
            [1, "a"],
            [2, "b"],
            [3, "c"]
        ])

        expect(zip(array_1, array_2, array_3)).to eq([
            ["a", 1, "w"],
            ["b", 2, "x"],
            ["c", 3, "y"]
        ])
    end
end
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I feel like I'm not defining my method properly, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `arr1.zip(arr2, arr3, arr4)` *is the same as* `arr1.zip(*[arr2, arr3, arr4])`. If you look at the doc for [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) you will see that it refers to the first form. You therefore could substitute the second form, with the splat. `arr1.zip([arr2, arr3, arr4])` would give you a different, unwanted, result. For example, `[1,2].zip *[[3,4], [5,6]] #=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]`, whereas  `[1,2].zip [[3,4], [5,6]] #=> [[1, [3, 4]], [2, [5, 6]]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to splat the `arrays` variable back out to arguments:

```rb
def zip(array, *arrays)
  array.zip(*arrays)
end
```